# Posting Data Limit PHP

Tags: php, html

I am having more than 1000 checkboxes in a form with same name as "users[]". And I am requesting these input elements in a php file. But I am getting only 950 users data. Is there any limit for posting data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what server are you using?

Comment: PHP has a `max_input_vars` ini setting that defaults to 1000, see http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

Comment: I bet that is a fun form to fill out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to php.ini:

```
max_input_vars = 2000
```